# Find the observation with the given ID, hapi Fhir

Tags: java, hapi, hl7-fhir

Bundle response = client.search()
                  .forResource("Observation")
                 .where(....)
                  .returnBundle(Bundle.class)
                  .execute();

Searched a whole while and still can not get the answer. 
I am using hapi fhir http://hapifhir.io/, and using Java.

Comment: I wanted to deleted this question, how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Unless you figured it out already, you need to add the class in the forRsource():

```
Bundle response = client.search() .forResource(Observation.class)
.where(....) .returnBundle(Bundle.class) .execute();
```

And if you have more than 10 Entries, you should have a look at https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/example/BundleFetcher.java
which reads all the pages in the Bundle and adds it to your Bundle object!